# "Unfortunately Application has Stopped" error is displayed when using Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am not able to figure out what am I missing. I am trying to implement a simple Google Map in my Main Activity. A google map should simply be displayed in the MainActivity.

Google API Key is correctly updated in the Manifest file. I have google-play-services_lib.jar included in my project. Google API 18 was selected as "Compile with" while creating a new Android Project in Eclipse.

Code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.maptest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

Code in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maptest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission         
   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MyActualKey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
02-26 22:50:40.075: D/AndroidRuntime(14428): Shutting down VM
02-26 22:50:40.075: W/dalvikvm(14428): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maptest/com.example.maptest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at com.example.maptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    ... 11 more
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-26 22:50:40.177: E/AndroidRuntime(14428):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Eclipse Emulator taking a lot of time to restart I will post it as soon as it runs. Give me some time.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the logcat data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You don't have meta-tag specified for google play services version. There should be 2 meta-tags - your map key and play services version:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

2) Android Emulator doesn't have GooglePlayServices installed. Use real device

**UPDATE**

3) Since you use `FragmentActivity` from support library, you have to use support map fragment as well. Replace your `activity_main` layout with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I included the metadata which you suggested. On the emulator I still got the same issue. I copied the .apk file to my Galaxy S3, but no luck.

Comment: @PD works like a charm. Thanks buddy. Cant vote up this answer as I don't have that much of reputation score.